# cmake - CMakeLists.txt is not in root folder (but is included in source)

Tags: c++, cmake, libpng

I'm trying to compile a libpng library. The thing is that I need a specific version of this library - 1.2.37 - because the project I'm using it in is written with this version.
I've found the source code of this version [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm) (GnuWin32 project).

But the folder structure looks something like this:

```
libpng-1.2.37-src/
   contrib/
   projects/
   scripts/
      CMakeLists.txt
   png.h
   pngread.c
   pngwrite.c
   ...
```

See, the CMakeLists.txt is one level deeper than the source files.

I've tried:

1. source directory *libpng-1.2.37-src/* -> resulted in error: The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt
2. source directory *libpng-1.2.37-src/scripts* -> resulted in multiple errors: File libpng-1.2.37-src/scripts/scripts/libpng.pc.in does not exist.
3. copy CMakeLists.txt from */scripts* to */libpng-1.2.37-src* and set source directory to */libpng-1.2.37-src* -> resulted in error: The source "/libpng-1.2.37-src/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/libpng-1.2.37-src/scripts/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.

What should I do to make it work? I don't know why the CMakeLists.txt file would be included if it can't be used.

Comment: I believe you should try `3.` again, but wipe the binary directory before that. The error comes from changing the source dir while keeping the cache intact - it should work if you start in a fresh binary dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `INSTALL` file explicitely says:

```
If you want to use "cmake" (see www.cmake.org), copy CMakeLists.txt
from the "scripts" directory to this directory and type

   cmake . [-DPNG_MMX=YES] -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path
   make
   make install
```

And as a side note, before this it says that the classic way to install it is:

```
On Unix/Linux and similar systems, you can simply type

    ./configure [--prefix=/path]
    make check
    make install
```

It sounds like you did right with 3), however you forgot to cleanup the build dir before trying again.

Comment: Why do I feel like this answer is telling me there's a solution somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

If it's library which you use in your project you can build it automatically via technique called 'superbuild' (use ExternalProject_Add). 
By specifying SOURCE_SUBDIR as is described [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/ExternalProject.html) to subdirectory with CMakeLists.txt you can do something like this

```
  ExternalProject_Add(libpng
  GIT_REPOSITORY    url-to-your-repository.git
  GIT_TAG           v1.2.37
  SOURCE_SUBDIR     "scripts"
```